# Pandas: type of file to save to contain dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, file

I'm working on some `datasets` contains many `DateTime` variables. I always save a `.csv` file after the data cleaning. However, when I load the file to pandas next time, I have to convert `dtypes` again and it will take a long time. Thus, I wonder if there is a type of file I can save with Pandas to avoid this.

Comment: Example code of how you are saving and loading would help people who want to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can serialize your object using `pickle`. Thankfully `pandas` has a native function to serialize and export your DataFrames. Just export using

```
df.to_pickle('your_file.pkl')
```

From the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

Then, you can load again your DataFrame using

```
df = pandas.read_pickle('your_file.pkl')
```

Comment: just tried to save a .pkl file and it works and all the dtypes are saved. meanwhile, the file size is almost four times less than the .csv having the same data. However, I wonder if there is any downside to save a pkl.file since I never heard it before.

Comment: No there is not a downside using a pkl file. I guess if you only want to save the data and not the objects then a csv is more appropriate though. If your question is answered please remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: A possible downside is I believe saving a pkl with one version of Pandas and opening it with another will raise a warning.  It probably could have accidental behaviour too(?  Otherwise the warning would never have existed in the first place)